# how to solve Zend\Mail\Protocol\Exception\RuntimeException

Tags: php, email, zend-framework

I want to send email using the zend framework 2,
I got the this error : A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. from the file :

> F:\xampp1\htdocs\ZendFramework\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mail\Protocol\AbstractProtocol.php:209,

I'm using the

```
$message = new Message();$message->setBody('This is the body');
$message->setFrom('kinjalshah96@gmail.com');$message->addTo( $data['email']);
$message->setSubject('Test subject');
$smtpOptions = new SmtpOptions();
$smtpOptions->setHost('smtp.gmail.com')
    ->setName('smtp.gmail.com')
    ->setConnectionConfig(array(
        'username' => 'kinjalshah96@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'mypassword',
        'ssl' => 'tls',
        'port' => 587,
        'host' => 'localhost:8080',) );
$transport = new Smtp($smtpOptions);
$transport->send($message);
```

if I'm using the `$transport = new Smtp();` then it give the error :

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

can you please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue using:

```
$smtpOptions->setHost('smtp.gmail.com')                                             
            ->setName('smtp.gmail.com')
            ->setPort(587)
            ->setConnectionClass('login')
            ->setConnectionConfig(array(
                               'username' => 'kinjalshah96@gmail.com',
                               'password' => 'mypassword',
                               'ssl' => 'tls',
                               'host'=>'localhost:8080',                                                                 
                             )
                  );
```